# Nuxt 3 Server middleware

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify, nuxtjs3

good people!

I'm building an app with nuxt3 and I need to set up a serverMiddleware. It's my first time using it so I might be doing it wrong.

The problem I'm facing right now is that on production, it's returning a 404 error.

I need to write code that creates a markdown file upon form submission and push changes to github.

Middleware code:

```
import fs from "fs";
import { resolve } from "path";
import path from "path";
import simpleGit from 'simple-git';
const git = simpleGit();

export default async function (app) {
  const req = app.node.req;
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const {fileName, content} = await readBody(app);
    const __dirname = path.resolve(path.dirname(""));
    const filePath = resolve(__dirname, `./content/products/${fileName}.md`);

    try {
      await fs.promises.writeFile(filePath, content);
      try {
        await git.cwd(resolve(__dirname, './'));
        await git.add('.');
        await git.commit(`Added new file: ${filePath}`);
        await git.push();
        console.log(`Commited and pushed changes to repository`);
        res.status(200);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('Error committing and pushing changes to Git repository');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Error generating Markdown file");
    }
  } else {return}
}
```

My Nuxt config:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({

  ssr:true,
  css: ["~/assets/styles/main.pcss"],
  modules: ["nuxt-icon",   '@nuxt/content'],
  content: {
    documentDriven: true
  },
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api/generate-markdown', handler: '~/server/middleware/generateMarkdown.js' }
  ],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
});
```

Is anything wrong with my setup ?
The whole app is deployed to netlify.